# How does Autocomplete in TwoTerm mode find the second term?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When I have TwoTerm selected for autocomplete mode and I do a search with "john smith is" the first 5 results are

- john smith is a
- john smith is active
- john smith is the
- john smith is an
- john smith is also

Can I expect that all of these results appear in an index field as a phrase or how does autocomplete infer the next term (a, active, the, an, also). With search mode set to all it doesn't return any results for these phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these results do not exist in the index but the phrases 
`is a`
`is active`
`is the`
`is an`
`is also`
 do exist in the index.

Please take a look at the [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/autocomplete-in-azure-search-now-in-public-preview/) which explains the different AutoCompletModes.
In `TwoTerms` mode, Autocomlete takes the last incomplete token and returns 2 terms only if they exist as a phrase in the index. So, only the last incomplete token is used and all other tokens are simply ignored.

If you are looking for a complete phrase match, I'd recommend issuing a search query and not suggest.